# How to determine Python3 ctypes .argtypes from C function signature?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I'm writing a ctypes interface to a 3rd party DLL (I have no control over the DLL).

My code seems to work, but I fear I'm setting up `.argtypes` wrong.

The signature of the C function I'm trying to call is:

```
int GetData(unsigned short option, unsigned char* buffer, int bufferLength, int &actualLength);
```

`option` indicates the kind of data requested, `buffer` points to a buffer I supply, `bufferLength` is the length of the buffer in bytes.

The DLL function writes into the buffer, and puts the number of bytes it actually wrote into `actualLength`.

My code:

```
import ctypes

dll = ctypes.CDLL("dll_name.dll")

def GetData(option):

    BUFSIZE = 6

    buf = bytearray(BUFSIZE)

    ptr_to_buf = (ctypes.c_char*len(buf)).from_buffer(buf)

    actualLength = ctypes.c_int()

    dll.GetData.argtypes = (ctypes.c_ushort, 
                            ctypes.c_char_p, 
                            ctypes.c_int, 
                            ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))

    dll.GetData.restype = int

    dll.GetData(option, 
                ptr_to_buf, 
                BUFSIZE, 
                ctypes.byref(actualLength))

    return (buf, actualLength.value)
```

Does the call to `GetData()` accurately reflect the .argtypes?

1. Is it OK to pass `ptr_to_buf` as a `ctypes.c_char_p` as I'm doing here?
2. Is it OK to pass a `ctypes.byref` into a `ctypes.POINTER` as I'm doing here?
3. When would be it be necessary to use `.pointer` instead of `.byref?` I did read the ctype docs, I know they say `.byref` is faster, but I'm not clear on when `.pointer` is needed.
4. Is there anything else I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: That's all perfectly fine.  It might be more natural to use `c_void_p` instead of `c_char_p`, but the net effect should be the same, so I wouldn't touch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.argtypes` is fine.  You *may* want `POINTER(c_ubyte)` to completely agree with the prototype, but often `c_char_p` is easier to work with.

> 1. Is it OK to pass ptr_to_buf as a ctypes.c_char_p as I'm doing here?

Yes.  An array is passed as a pointer of the same element type.

> 2. Is it OK to pass a ctypes.byref into a ctypes.POINTER as I'm doing here?

Yes.

> 3. When would be it be necessary to use .pointer instead of .byref? I did read the ctype docs, I know they say .byref is faster, but I'm not clear on when .pointer is needed.

Create a `pointer` when you need a concrete pointer.  I've rarely used `pointer`.  Say you had this code in C and had some reason to mimic it:

```c
int x = 5;
int* y = &x;
```

The Python equivalent would be:

```py
x = c_int(5)
y = pointer(x)
```

> 4. Is there anything else I'm doing wrong here?

`.restype` should have a `ctype` type.  `.restype = c_int` would be correct.